# like a private group post in fb

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

By now I can make a user like a wall post, but the problem is when i need to make a user like a private group post by javascript sdk.
I can't even see the the feeds in group using https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN it shows a blank page, data  written to it, is there any problem with my token no. and one thing more here do i need to user my app acccess token no or user_access_token, If user_access_token no then how can i get it b'cause i can only manage to get app_access_token no which is fixed by method https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials. but when i try to get groups feed using facebook api tool it shows there. So what is the problem
Sorry for so many questions and Thanks i adavance.

Comment: This is almost unreadable. I cannot understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need various permissions to view and publish in Groups. You need `publish_stream` to publish to groups and additionally `user_groups` to interact/view in groups.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/